# how to use bootstrap with Yii?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have been trying to implement twitter bootstrap extension in Yii but cannot do it.

I am following the guide below to install it with Yii.

http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html

I copied and pasted the following code in my main config file as described in above guide.

```
// Define a path alias for the Bootstrap extension as it's used internally.
// In this example we assume that you unzipped the extension under     protected/extensions.
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

return array(
'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory
'modules'=>array(
    'gii'=>array(
        'generatorPaths'=>array(
            'bootstrap.gii',
        ),
    ),
),
'components'=>array(
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
),
);
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer you need to put the following in your main.php file of your protected/views/layouts folder anywhere between `<head>` and `</head>` tag.

```
    <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerAllCss(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like a piece of cake. I guess problem with you is your path to bootstrap extension. I would suggest to put complete path instead of relative path. Once it get working you can try to make the path relative.

Example:
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', '/var/www/yoursite/application/extensions/bootstrap');

Instead of:
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(**FILE**).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

This should work for you! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am also use that but the answer is not come but I got another way so you follow that I tell.

I think you want new themes so"

1. Go to download themes from yii framework.
2. Copy that folder then past to themes folder
3. config->main.php->'theme'=>'grey-stripes', protected go config folder  go  main.php go and copy  'theme'=>'grey-stripes',

Your new themes are ready